# Identityserver4/oidc sends the login to the incorrect domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I set up Identity Server 4 and my application on the same server both being run by IIS.

I then set up a proxy server to hide the applications using SSL-offloading.

For some unkown reason, when I try and log into my application I'm sent to the wrong domain name. Example.

I have https://IDS.com & https://myapplication.com

When I open myapplication.com and try to access a page that requires authentication i'm supposed to be redirected to https://IDS.com/connect/authorize...

instead it tries to send me to
https://myapplication.com/connect/authorize... which gives me a 404 error. However if I keep the url in the browser, and switch the domain name to IDS.com it works as expected.

Is there a way to make ids request the correct domain name?

I fiddled around with my iis rewrite rules a bit to see if i could goose it. I was semi successful in that I could redirect it to my identity server instead of my application for authorization. However, the domain name remains the same and none of the CSS or javascript works. So that work around is a no go.

`      .AddOpenIdConnect(AuthorizationConsts.OidcAuthenticationScheme, options
      =>
     {

```
     options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
     options.Authority = "http://DNS:5000";//DNS for IDS 



     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
     options.ClientId = AuthorizationConsts.OidcClientId;
     //https://IDS.com gives me 403 error so i'm using the DNS:{Port} 

     options.Scope.Clear();
     options.Scope.Add(AuthorizationConsts.ScopeOpenId);
     options.Scope.Add(AuthorizationConsts.ScopeProfile);
     options.Scope.Add(AuthorizationConsts.ScopeEmail);
     options.Scope.Add(AuthorizationConsts.ScopeRoles);



     options.SaveTokens = true;

     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
     {
         NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
         RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
     };

     options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
     {

         OnMessageReceived = OnMessageReceived,
         OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider

     };
```

As stated the expected result is to change the domain name from https://myapplication.com => https://IDS.com so the site can properlly authenticate users and avoid http 404

Comment: What happens if you hit the authority url using the browser on the server?

Comment: Same result as described above. URL rewrite worked.

Answer (score 0):

After a weeks of having all sorts of issues with getting IDS and my app to work together in production I finally figured it out. I don't believe this to be the ideal solution since I used URL rewrite, but it works.

On Proxy Server Open IIS Manager. Select the site that is redirecting traffic. Select URL Rewrite. Add a rule for inbound traffic and for the pattern put: (.*) Conditions add {URL} Matches Pattern :  connect/authorize. then instead of using rewrite for the action select Redirect. Put the domain name in which you want to connect to: https://ids.com/{R:1}
check Append query string. Screen shots below.

I really hope this helps someone.

[image]